# JavaScript and CSS - Content replacement/parsing

Tags: javascript, css, regex, parsing

I have a JavaScript string that contain CSS code.

With this string i want to obtain 2 things with a loop and **without regex**

first thing: selector/s

second thing: properties of the obtained selector/s

My concept:

```
var myResult = [], myString = /* CSS content */;

while(myString.length > 0)
{
    var
    mySelector = /* Obtain the first selector occurrence. */,
    myRules = /* Obtain the rules of the founded selector */;

    myResult.push(mySelector, myRules);

    myString = myString.replace(mySelector, null);
    myString = myString.replace(myRules, null);

    // then now loop and find the next first selector and his rules.
}
```

Example:

```
var myResult = [], myString = "main { color: #405050; margin: 0; } hr, progress { width: 100%; }";

while(myString.length > 0)
{
    var
    mySelector = /* Obtain the first selector occurrence */,
    myRules = /* Obtain the rules of the founded selector */;

    myResult.push(mySelector, myRules);

    myString = myString.replace(mySelector, null);
    myString = myString.replace(myRules, null);

    // then now loop and find the next first selector and his rules.
}

// now myResult must contain: "main", "color: red; margin: 0;", "hr, progress", "width: 100%"
```

Someone can help me to do this algorithm without using regex?

Comment: Can you provide the possible values of your variables?

Comment: And an explanation of why you don't want to use regex? (It isn't, of course, a full solution, but it could form *part* of the solution; arbitrarily ruling it out needs an explanation.)

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar i asked this question for this..

Comment: **And** is this in a browser environment, or not? (It matters quite a lot to the answer.)

Comment: @VasileAlexandruPeste: No, what Muneeb is saying is: Show us your input string, and expected values from that input string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i don't want to use regex because they are slow on big content.

Comment: @VasileAlexandruPeste: Worry about performance problems when you run into performance problems, not before. JS regex on modern engines is really fast, almost certainly faster than any ad-hoc thing you're going to come up with.

Comment: What does it matter if it is in the browser? the engine that interprets JavaScript is not the same?

Answer (score 0):

this would work for u

```
var myString = "main { color: #405050; margin: 0; }";
            var selector = "";            
            var myResult = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((myString[i] >= 65 && myString[i] <= 90) || (myString[i] >= 97 && myString[i] <= 122) || myString[i] == '.' || myString[i] == '#') 
                /* keep going if you find any thing that is . or # of alphabets */
                {
                    selector += myString[i];
                }
                else
                {

                    for (var j = i + 1; j < myString.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if ((myString[j] >= 65 && myString[j] <= 90) || (myString[j] >= 97 && myString[j] <= 122)) // rule start
                        /* keep going unless the rule ends */
                        {
                            var currRule = "";
                            for (var l = j; l < myString.Length; l++)
                            {
                                currRule += myString[l];
                                if (myString[l] == ';')
                                {
                                    j = l;
                                    i = l;
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                            myResult.push(mySelector, myRules);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```